# Gradle is downloading every time I open a project on android studio

Tags: java, android-studio, gradle, build.gradle

So we have an app development class in our school and this issue has came up for the first time since this class has started.

Whenever we login and open android studio, even if you create a new project or open an existing one it downloads gradle 7.0.2 again and then it builds. We make our projects using Java.

I would really love any solution it’s been 2 weeks and we can’t do anything in the class because of this.

I don’t t know a lot about android studio as i am still a student. The .gradle folder is still in the project directory but it still downloads it. We tried downloading the gradle zip file online and paste it manually but it still did not work.

Comment: I don't use Gradle, but presumably, if you *install* it, then it would have no need to do that..?

Comment: Typically, Gradle downloads to `~/.gradle/caches/...` and after downloading once, it uses the cached version.  That said, if you've specified alternate locs using `gradle-wrapper.properties` or some other mechanism, it could cause this.  If no config changes are in play, you could try deleting `~/.gradle`, which would force a one-time download, but might clean it up for others?

Comment: You could check whether your account gets cleaned up each time you log out and that throws away Gradle's cache. But if it's not that, I don't think anybody here can help you, only your sysadmin.